# Gif request seems to get stuck in Firebug when tracking file downloads

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, download, firebug, query-string

I'm tracking file downloads from my site but something awkward is happening. When I download something with firebug open, the **.gif request seems to get stuck**: the "progress wheel" just keeps on turning and I can't open / copy the request to see its parameters.

[image]
The code I use for the `href` is:

`<a href='http://www.mywebsite.com/downloads/supermarket.sav' title='Download Test Data File (file size around 9kB)' onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '.sav', 'Download', 'supermarket.sav']);">supermarket.sav</a>`

That isn't normal, now is it? Is the code wrong? Despite all this, the download seems to be registered correctly in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Have you instead tried using Google Chrome? It has a dedicated extension -- [Google Analytics Debugger](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fgoogle-analytics-debugger%2Fjnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna%3Fhl%3Den&ei=h0KBUp_LEIrOhAf0mIH4BA&usg=AFQjCNGTv_4m9B4Xa50M46BAYT_NlAlK8w&bvm=bv.56146854,d.ZG4) -- that allows you to see the precise details of what's being tracked in the Developer Tools console e.g.

Here's a sample of the debug data:

```
_gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-XXXXXX-3]":  ga_debug.js:24
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":  ga_debug.js:24
Track Pageview ga_debug.js:24
Tracking beacon sent!
utmwv=5.4.5d&utms=1&utmn=991384789&utmhn=davidsimpson.me&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=2560x1440&utmvp=1529x1054&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=11.9%20r900&utmdt=David%20Simpson&utmhid=360476275&utmr=-&utmp=%2F&utmht=1384203699409&utmac=UA-XXXXXX-3&utmcc=__utma%3D24779695.1234567890.1370042497.1382213465.1384203699.11%3B%2B__utmz%3D24779695.1370042497.1.1.utmcsr%3Durlm.co%7Cutmccn%3D(referral)%7Cutmcmd%3Dreferral%7Cutmcct%3D%2Fwww.davidsimpson.me%3B&utmu=q~ ga_debug.js:24
Account ID               : UA-XXXXXX-3
Page Title               : David Simpson
Host Name                : davidsimpson.me
Page                     : /
Referring URL            : -
Hit ID                   : 360476275
Visitor ID               : 1234567890
Session Count            : 11
Session Time - First     : Sat Jun 01 2013 00:21:37 GMT 0100 (BST)
Session Time - Last      : Sat Oct 19 2013 21:11:05 GMT 0100 (BST)
Session Time - Current   : Mon Nov 11 2013 21:01:39 GMT 0000 (GMT)
Campaign Time            : Sat Jun 01 2013 00:21:37 GMT 0100 (BST)
Campaign Session         : 1
Campaign Count           : 1
Campaign Source          : urlm
Language                 : en-us
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 11.9 r900
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 2560x1440
Browser Size             : 1529x1054
Color Depth              : 24-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.4.5d
Cachebuster              : 991384789 ga_debug.js:24
```

It works with click events too :)